Create shell and then execute commands
I am trying to create a shell and then to execute commands within that process. The code compiles and executes but I get s empty string both from stdout and stderr and don't know why. already tried to debug but nothing, dont know what else to do.
pub struct Shell {
    child: Child,
    stdin: ChildStdin,
    stdout: ChildStdout,
    stderr: ChildStderr,
}

impl Shell {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Shell, io::Error> {
        #[cfg(unix)]
        let shell = "sh";

        #[cfg(unix)]
        let shell_arg = "-c";

        #[cfg(windows)]
        let shell = "cmd";

        #[cfg(windows)]
        let shell_arg = "/C";

        let mut cmd = Command::new(shell);
        cmd.arg(shell_arg)
           .stdin(Stdio::piped())
           .stdout(Stdio::piped())
           .stderr(Stdio::piped());

        let mut child = cmd.spawn()?;
        let stdin = child.stdin.take().ok_or_else(|| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Failed to open stdin"))?;
        let stdout = child.stdout.take().ok_or_else(|| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Failed to open stdout"))?;
        let stderr = child.stderr.take().ok_or_else(|| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Failed to open stderr"))?;

        Ok(Shell { child, stdin, stdout, stderr })
    }

    pub fn execute(&mut self, command: &str) -> Result<(String, String), io::Error> {
        writeln!(self.stdin, "{}", command)?;
    
        let mut stdout_buf = String::new();
        let mut stderr_buf = String::new();
    
        let mut stdout_reader = BufReader::new(&mut self.stdout);
        println!("test: {:?}", stdout_reader);
        let mut stderr_reader = BufReader::new(&mut self.stderr);
    
        stdout_reader.read_to_string(&mut stdout_buf)?;  // Read from stdout
        stderr_reader.read_to_string(&mut stderr_buf)?;  // Read from stderr
    
        Ok((stdout_buf, stderr_buf))
    }

    pub fn close(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        self.child.kill()?;
        self.child.wait()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}


They expect the code as an argument, not in stdin.

It looks like you're intending to execute multiple commands in this shell process. You can, however there is no standard mechanism to know when one command has finished its output (and thus .read_to_string() won't do that). So you can stream commands to the shell and stream its output, but you'll have a hard time associating the two.

You're using sh -c which takes commands as arguments.
You're trying to pass in a command on stdin.
From the bash man page.

-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the
first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the
positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is
used in warning and error messages.

$ sh -c
sh: -c: option requires an argument

$ sh -c 'echo "test"'
test

The std::process::Command docs have an example of this.
use std::process::Command;

let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    Command::new("cmd")
        .args(["/C", "echo hello"])
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process")
} else {
    Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("echo hello")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process")
};

let hello = output.stdout;

